# Thread Pool in Java slower than serial version

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have a [program](https://github.com/muhammed-enes-koroglu/gameSolver/commit/f3dbc229ac326cdd02c308eee2e38b89668ceb34) that expands a given node to find the next possible nodes (`children`) and save/return them in `childrenSet`. I first implemented this serially like this:

```
    private Set<ReversiState> getChildrenSerial() {

        HashSet<ReversiState> childrenSet = new HashSet<>();

        // For each piece of the player, add the children.
        for(int row=0; row<BOARD_SIZE; row++){
            for(int col=0; col<BOARD_SIZE; col++){

                // This is where the heavy work happens
                addChildrenForPosition(childrenSet, row, col);
            }
        }

        return childrenSet;
    }
```

When I run my program using this, it finishes in around 9.7 seconds. The minimax algorithm that uses this method can on average search for a depth of 7.0 nodes.

However, I wanted to be able to search deeper, as that is more desirable for the outcome I want. To do that, I tried to use Java's `ThreadPoolExecutor` as a static final in the same class. But got worse results.

```
private static final int NB_THREADS = 8;
private static final ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) 
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NB_THREADS);
```

And implemented the `getChildrenParallel` method. This is essentially the same as `getChildrenSerial`, but gives the task `addChildrenForPosition` to the thread pool to handle.

```
    private Set<ReversiState> getChildrenParallel() {

        HashSet<Future<Void>> threadResults = new HashSet<>();
        HashSet<ReversiState> childrenSet = new HashSet<>();

        // For each piece of the player, add the children.
        for(int row=0; row<BOARD_SIZE; row++){
            for(int col=0; col<BOARD_SIZE; col++){

                // Multi-threading takes final variables.
                final Integer rowFinal = row;
                final Integer colFinal = col;

                Submit a task to the thread pool.
                Future<Void> future = executor.submit(

                         // This is the method where the heavy work happens
                    () -> addChildrenForPosition(childrenSet, rowFinal, colFinal), 
                    null);
                threadResults.add(future);
                }
            }
        }

        // Wait for all tasks to finish.
        for(Future<Void> future : threadResults){
            try{
                future.get();
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return childrenSet;
    }
```

I of course expected this to run faster than the serial version as the threads are emulated by the OS to somewhat give the resemblance of actual parallelism. However this takes on average 11 seconds to run and the depth reduces to an average of 6.3. It is slightly worse than the serial implementation when I expected at least a doubling on performance.

Why is this happening? Is it because it takes some time to submit to the thread pool? Is the overhead too much for how small the task is? What can I do to correct it?

P.S.: I am running this on Windows 11.

Comment: Is the question too long? Should I try to shorten it? I feel it's all related though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Java Concurrency In Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) writes:

> The actual cost of context switching varies across platforms, but a good rule of thumb is that a context switch costs the equivalent of 5,000 to 10,000 clock cycles, or several microseconds on most current processors.

They explain:

> Context switches are not free; thread scheduling requires manipulating shared data structures in the OS and JVM. The OS and JVMuse the same CPUs your program does; more CPU time spent in JVM and OS code means less is available for your program. But OS and JVM activity is not the only cost of context switches. When a new thread is switched in, the data it needs is unlikely to be in the local processor cache, so a context switch causes a flurry of cache misses, and thus threads run a little more slowly when they are first scheduled.

For your program, I'd expect cache misses to be quite severe, indeed. Your code processes each node in the search tree in a seperate thread. So one thread will read the board state (from main memory), create a slightly modified copy, and rather than processing that copy while it is at hand, schedule its processing for a later time. One would be hard pressed to find a less efficient way to access main memory ...

If you wish to make this concurrent, a `ForkJoinPool` might be a better fit. But frankly, you can achieve far greater performance improvements by improving your algorithm. For instance, you are currently copying the entire board every time you consider a move. Updating an existing board would be far faster ...

I should also point out that your code is incorrectly synchronized. For instance, a `HashSet` is not safe for concurrent access.

To conclude, multithreading can help with processing deep state trees, but

- should be done with rather coarse tasks to make efficient use of CPU caches,
- requires good understanding of when and how to protect shared data structures from concurrent modification,
- and tends to be far less impactful than the use of efficient algorithms

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am creating a new child using the new board. Each child has a different board. I don't see how updating the same board would solve that? Using the same board would mean that every child eventually has the same board.

Comment: Thanks for the warning about synchronization. I am now using ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet(). Don't think it has any noticeable effect on the performance though.

Comment: Every child having the same board is the point, because the time spent copying boards is likely greater than the speed gained by a using multiple threads, even if you coordinate them well. That is, a single threads, board sharing algorithm isk likely to be faster than a multi-threaded, board copying algorithm.

Comment: I don't see how all children sharing the same board would be possible, as their boards are their only distinguishing aspect. Do you maybe mean that it might be better if the children don't have each their own board, but possibly they could hold a log of what changes have been made since the starting node. And they could generate their board when they need it. This might indeed work if the depth of the child from the starting node isn't too big. Otherwise it would be wasting the compute resources.